# Country flags unicode char

Tags: unicode, characters, newunicodechar

I am trying to define new unicode chars for country flags. Unfortunately flags are encoded using **two** regional indicator symbols according to the ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 two-letter country codes. So  for example is  . (To make it visible here I just added a space between the two characters.)

The problem is, that both `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` (pdfTeX) and `\newunicodechar` (XeTeX and LuaTeX) only accept one char. That's why

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{}{\rule{1.3em}{1em}}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

for example does not work. Can I trick TeX into thinking a combination of two chars is one char? Or are there any other ideas for a workaround?

Comment: you can't define a "Unicode char" (unless you _are_ the Unicode consortium.  Normally you would just use a TeX command `\newcommand\DE{..}` do you need to use a form with no backslash? (which is easy of you do not use capital letters for anything else, harder otherwise.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm working on a package to make [Emoji One](http://emojione.com) available in LaTeX. You can have a look at it here: https://github.com/benjamin-weiss/emojione-latex For every symbol I use `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` or `\newunicodechar` to make it "directly" available, but I also define a macro. So the german flag for example is already accessible via `\emojiflagde`. But I think it would be confusing for the users if the flags are only available via a TeX command, but every other symbol works directly.

Comment: sorry I didn't spot that your DE were not just the ascii characters DE, If you enter  directly then I suppose most natural would be for the font to ligature that to the flag, but if that is not the case you could make them active and define each one to look ahead.

Comment: oh, it's not a font, rather a collection of images?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes it is a collection of images. But can I still define the regional indicator symbols as active and look ahead? What does look ahead exactly mean?

Comment: Is there the reverse where we want the flag logo to render instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can emulate what basically `utf8` does:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newunicodechar{}{\flags_D:n}
\newunicodechar{}{\flags_U:n}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \flags_D:n
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {}{Germany}
    {}{Denmark}
   }
   {BAD}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \flags_U:n
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {}{United~Kingdom}
    {}{United~States}
   }
   {BAD}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Here is 

Here is 

Here is 

Here is 

\end{document}
```

[image]

A version that works also with `pdflatex` (weird errors are to be expected if regional indicator symbols not appear in pairs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex\else
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\fi
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newunicodechar{}{ \flags_print:n {D} }
\newunicodechar{}{ \flags_print:n {U} }

\bool_if:nTF { \sys_if_engine_luatex_p: || \sys_if_engine_xetex_p: }
 {
  \cs_new:Nn \flags_print:n
   {
    \flags_print_unicode:nn { #1 }
   }
 }
 {
  \cs_new:Nn \flags_print:n
   {
    \peek_charcode:NTF ^^f0
     {
      \flags_print_eightbit:nnnnn { #1 }
     }
     {
      BAD
     }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \flags_print_unicode:nn
 {
  \use:c { flags_#1:n } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \flags_print_eightbit:nnnnn
 {
  \use:c { flags_#1:n } { #2#3#4#5 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \flags_D:n
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {}{Germany}
    {}{Denmark}
   }
   {BAD}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \flags_U:n
 {
  \str_case:nnF {#1}
   {
    {}{United~Kingdom}
    {}{United~States}
   }
   {BAD}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Here is 

Here is 

Here is 

Here is 

\end{document}
```

It would be possible to add a check on the next character also for Unicode engines, but it seems more crucial for `pdflatex`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This seems to be exactly what I need. But why is there a `\tl_to_str:n { #1 }` in `\flags_D:n` but not in `\flags_U:n`? The "U-version" seems to be working just fine.

Comment: @Benjamin Because I forgot to fix it. ;-)

Comment: I thought I could easily adapt your solution for pdfTeX by replacing `\newunicodechar{}{\flags_D:n}` by `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{127465}{\flags_D:n}`. Unfortunately this isn't the case. I'm still looking into it, but if you already know why that is, maybe you can post also a solution for pdfTeX.

Comment: @Benjamin With `pdftex` it's more complicated. Added.

Comment: Still trying to understand all the code. I just started learning LaTeX3. But couldn't I just prevent the "weird errors" by replacing `{BAD}` with `{#1}`?

Comment: Also a sequence like    would result in  instead of just `BAD`.

Comment: @Benjamin I don't follow; if the combination is not defined, you get an error (here represented by `BAD`), notwithstanding what you see on the editor window.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36065/discussion-between-benjamin-and-egreg).