# How are charcodes categorized in LaTeX3/expl3?

Tags: unicode, expl3, latex3

I don't understand the following part from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295205/country-flags-unicode-char/295217#295217) solution:

```
\peek_charcode:NTF ^^f0
```

What does the '^^f0' mean? Where does it come from? I looked into interface3.pdf and couldn't find anything.

The unicode replacement works nicely for 1f1e9-1f1ea (, german flag), 1f468-1f3ff (, emoji skin color variation) and 1f3f3-1f308 (☠, pirate flag). But not on 1f3f4-2620 (, rainbow flag).

I guess it is connected to the fact, that '2620' in the last example is not 5 digits long? I fiddled a bit with the '^^f0' and every variation (i.e. '^^0f', '^^ab', '^^08', ...) either led to an error or didn't combine either of the mentioned emoji.

The question, again: How does '^^f0' work?

Comment: this is primitive tex syntax (and with the two `^^` form works even in classic tex). it just means the character with code f0 so U+00F0 luatex and xetex extend the syntax to allow `^^^^2020` to refer to a larger range

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is primitive tex syntax (and with the two `^^` form works even in classic tex). it just means the character with code hex f0 so U+00F0 luatex and xetex extend the syntax to allow `^^^^2020` to refer to a larger range

so you do not need  expl3 or even latex, just primitive tex syntax

```
\show ^^77
```

produces

```
> the letter w.
l.2 \show ^^77
```

as in fact does

```
\sho^^77 w
```

which produces

```
> the letter w.
l.2 \show w

?
```

the `^^` substitution is at a very early stage even before command names are tokenized.

Luatex uses an extended syntax allowing four or 6 `^` (but not 3 or 5) so you are probably looking for

```
^^^^^^01f3f4
```

In xetex or luatex  the character U+1F1EA is a single character token with character code hex 1f1ea so it would not match a test for being the character with code hex f0, in pdftex it is the four character tokens with character codes hex f0 9f 87 aa (because character=byte=octet in pdftex) so if you look for the next character you just see the first byte of the utf8 encoding which is the character hex f0.

Comment: Thanks, that's a start.
But why does ^^f0 match 1f1ea, 1f308, ... in pdflatex?
\show gives me \UTFviii@four@octets but 1f1ea etc. have 5 octets, haven't they?

Comment: @genericFJS no utf8 encoded character takes more than four octets in UTf-8  see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description

Comment: U+1f1ea in UTF-8 is: F0 9F 87 AA

Comment: Ok, I confused something. But that still does not explain to me, why ^^f0 matches 1f1ea and not 2620 when using `\peek_charcode` with pdflatex. And why does it not match anything when using lualatex/xelatex?

Comment: @genericFJS  in xetex the character is a single character token with character code hex 1f1ea so it would not match a test for being the character with code hex f0, in pdftex it is the four character tokens with character codes hex f0 9f 87 aa (because character=byte=octet in pdftex)  so if you look for the next character you just see the first byte of the utf8 encoding which is the character hex F0

Comment: That explains it all. Could you edit your last comment into the answer, then I can mark it as an accepted answer. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: @genericFJS done