# Compare macro names instead of meaning

Tags: xetex, expl3, latex3

I want to replace unicode character pairs in XeTeX similar to [Country flags unicode char](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295205/country-flags-unicode-char). I don't want to specify every option (every country code) and want to be flexible for other emoji (skin color variations, other non-country-code flags etc.). The problem with the code in the mentioned answer is, that it doesn't allow single pairable characters (even if I modify the False-statement accordingly). I already tried tackling this problem (but failed in part): [Peek ahead and process characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397250/peek-ahead-and-process-characters)

I now have another possible solution, which is flawed as well:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \single_uni:n #1 { #1 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \dual_uni:n {
    \peek_catcode:NF ## {
        #1\token_if_protected_macro:NTF \l_peek_token {+} {}
    }
}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \cyrillic:n {
    #1
}

\newunicodechar{➀}{\single_uni:n{a}}
\newunicodechar{➁}{\dual_uni:n{b}}
\newunicodechar{➂}{\dual_uni:n{c}}
\newunicodechar{И}{\cyrillic:n{x}}
% ... hundreds more single/dual_uni characters !
\begin{document}
➀\par   % a
➁\par   % b
➀➁\par  % ab
➁➀\par  % b+a
➂➀\par  % c+a
➂➁➀\par % c+b+a
➀{➁}\par    % ab
$➁$\par % b
➁И\par  % bx, NOT b+x
\end{document}
```

If I enter "➁➀" the result should be "➁+➀"/"b+a". As you can see the code works for the intended purpose, but it works for an unintended purpose, too: other protected macros (like the `\cyrillic:n` macro).

I know, that I can't directly compare the meanings, as they are different, even if they call the same macro (the one is `\protected macro:->\dual_uni:n {b}`and the other `\protected macro:->\dual_uni:n {c}`).

Is there a way to compare the macro names (the meaning without the parameters so to speak) like the following (pseudo-) code snippet?

```
% wishfull thinking code (instead of \token_if_protected_macro:NTF):
\token_if_eq_macro_name:NNT \l_peek_token \dual_uni:n { + }
\token_if_eq_macro_name:NNT \l_peek_token \single_uni:n { + }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of a [solution by Manuel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/397493/136226), I was able to implement the following solution which is based on comparing the peeked "first token inside the definition of a macro" to the expected string:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn \fjs_string_first_delimit_q_nil:Nw #1 #2 \q_nil { \token_to_str:N #1 }

\cs_new:Npn \fjs_obtain_first_token:N #1 {
    \exp_after:wN \fjs_string_first_delimit_q_nil:Nw #1 xxxxxxxxx \q_nil
    \space
}

\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \fjs_tokeninside_case:Nn #1 #2 { TF, T, F } {
    \str_set:Nx \l_fjs_first_token_str {\fjs_obtain_first_token:N #1}
    \str_case_x:nnTF {\l_fjs_first_token_str} {
        #2
    } {
        \prg_return_true:
    }{
        \prg_return_false:
    }
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \fjs_uni:N #1 { #1 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \fjs_checkdual:N {
    \peek_catcode:NF ## {
        #1
        \token_if_macro:NT \l_peek_token {
            \fjs_tokeninside_case:NnT \l_peek_token {
                 { \fjs_uni:N } { } 
                 { \fjs_checkdual:N } { } 
            } {
                +
            }
        }
    }
}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \fjs_cyrillic:n { #1 }

\newunicodechar{➀}{\fjs_uni:N a}
\newunicodechar{➁}{\fjs_checkdual:N b}
\newunicodechar{➂}{\fjs_checkdual:N c}
\newunicodechar{И}{\fjs_cyrillic:n{x}}
% ... hundreds more single/dual_uni characters !
\begin{document}
➀\par   % a
➁\par   % b
➀➁\par  % ab
➁➀\par  % b+a
➂➀\par  % c+a
➂➁➀\par % c+b+a
➀{➁}\par    % ab
$➁$\par % b
➁И\par  % bx, NOT b+x
\end{document}
```

In combination with the hex-replacement, as mentioned in the other linked question, the code in the header would look like this:

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \fjs_uni:N #1 { [\int_to_Hex:n { `#1 }] }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \fjs_uni:NN #1 #2 { [\int_to_Hex:n{`#1};\int_to_Hex:n{`#2}] }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \fjs_dualuni:N {
    \peek_catcode:NF ## {
        \token_if_macro:NTF \l_peek_token {
            \fjs_tokeninside_case:NnTF \l_peek_token {
                 { \fjs_uni:N } { } 
                 { \fjs_uni:NN } { } 
                 { \fjs_dualuni:N } { } 
            } {
                \fjs_uni:NN #1 
            } {
                \fjs_uni:N #1 
            }
        }{
            \fjs_uni:N #1
        }
    }
}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \fjs_cyrillic:n { #1 }

\newunicodechar{➀}{\fjs_uni:N ➀}
\newunicodechar{➁}{\fjs_dualuni:N ➁}
\newunicodechar{➂}{\fjs_dualuni:N ➂}
```

Comment: From this I would create a function that would take care about everything about obtaining the first token inside, so the code would be clearer, and apart from that, may be the naming conventions (`\l_jfs_peek_token`).

Comment: @Manuel Thank you for your feedback. I edited it accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it bad `\l_jfs_peek_str` should be correct. In any case, you could create your own conditional that does everything `\fjs_tokeninside_case:NnTF \l_peek_token { { \fjs_uni:N } { } { \fjs_uni:NN } { } } { <true> \fjs_uni:NN #1 } { <false> \fjs_uni:N #1 }` so that your code is clearer, and you separate each function and their definition.

Comment: @Manuel Thanks for your good advice. I implemented your suggestions… I hope I did the new conditional correctly :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you're after but I think `\peek_charcode:NTF` can help you achieve it. Does this help?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newunicodechar,expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newunicodechar{➀}{\some_macro:n{a}}
\newunicodechar{➁}{\some_macro:n{b}}
\cs_set:Npn \some_macro_alone:n #1 {=#1=}
\cs_set:Npn \some_macro:n #1
  {
    \some_macro_alone:n {#1}
    \peek_charcode:NT ➁ { + }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
[➀]\par
[➀{➁}]\par
[➁]\par
[➀➁]\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your idea. Sadly, this does not work for [➁➀]. I have updated my answer, to clarify what I want.

Comment: @genericFJS — well, yes :) I can see the problem now; you don't want to have 100s of case statements inside the code! Looking for a common "head" inside the token makes sense. Your solution below gives me an idea for something similar that's been bugging me for years in `unicode-math`.

Comment: I wish you the best with that :-) I still feel like I cheated by comparing some strings ;-)

Comment: @WillRobertson You mean the idea of making a few macros with `\macro:n {asdf}` and make each of them see the next one if they have `\macro:n` at the beginning inside? I mean, that's not new hehehe `\DOTSB` and family from amsmath. Although in this case I opted to expand the macro rather than get the info from `\meaning` which seems to be quite difficult in the original code.

Comment: @Manuel — nothing new under the sun, of course :) I think with my own code I'll need to insert a common marker that is gobbled (or maybe `\relax`) under normal conditions. I'd been ignoring this for years since the current code works, it's just a bit inelegant. So thanks for sparking the idea!